# Error: can't find properties of document 1

Tags: applescript

I asked a question last week about a portion of this script and had a couple of really helpful replies that sent me in the right direction. I realized I could add a little more to the end of the script and here's what I have. This script works perfectly about 80% of the time - when there is an error  it says can't find properties of document 1. I thought I fixed this by adding the line     set mydoc to document 1     Where it was added but I think it's still sometimes seen as an undefined variable. Is there a better way to state this?  One other problem is that sometimes I may have 2 or 3 files in the downloads folder. Do I need a repeat for each document?  The goal is to have the 3 spot colors added to the illustrator docs when opened. 
Here is what I have currently

```
tell application "Finder"
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer    "Job_Name")
set loc to desktop
set newfoldername to JobName
set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
make new folder at newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_Seps"}
make new folder at newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_DTG"}
set the clipboard to JobName
end tell

tell application "Finder"
open folder JobName
move (files of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Downloads") to newfo
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
open files in newfo
end tell

tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
set mydoc to document 1
set docColorSpace to color space of document 1
if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
set SpotColor to {cyan:21.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
else
set SpotColor to {red:206.0, green:219.0, blue:41.0}
end if
make new spot in document 1 with properties {name:"Highlight White", color type:spot color,  color:SpotColor}
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
set docColorSpace to color space of document 1
if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
set SpotColor to {cyan:11.0, magenta:100, yellow:30.0, black:0.0}
else
set SpotColor to {red:215.0, green:23.0, blue:111.0}
end if
make new spot in document 1 with properties {name:"Under Base", color type:spot color,   color:SpotColor}
end tell

tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
set docColorSpace to color space of document 1
if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
set SpotColor to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0, yellow:0.0, black:100.0}
else
set SpotColor to {red:35.0, green:34.0, blue:33.0}
end if
make new spot in document 1 with properties {name:"Spot Black", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor}
end tell
```

Comment: The title should describe the question.

Comment: Could you please format the code again? It is hardly readable as it is.

Comment: Sorry about the lame title and format - i emailed it to myself from work and posted this from my phone, although the first time I didn't format correctly either.

Comment: The formatting is still off. If you post this from your own Mac, the formatting should be OK. Just copy and paste directly from the script editor. Also make sure to 'accept' Regulus' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has lots of problems so I rewrote it for you. Note that I didn't check the Illustrator code because I do not have Illustrator... so if it doesn't work you'll just need to tweak it.

The main problem with your code is newfo. The path that the Finder generates when you create that folder is in a format only the Finder can understand. Illustrator will not understand that format. This is only something you would know by experience. Finder paths are described as...

```
file something of folder something of folder something of disk something
```

That style is unique to the Finder. Therefore if we need the path to be useful outside of the Finder we need to change that style into something other programs will understand. You'll see in my code below that I let the Finder get all of the files in newfo but I convert them into something Illustrator will know with "as alias list". It converts all of those Finder references in alias references which any program will understand.

So hopefully this code will help teach you. Keep practicing though, that's the only way to get better. Good luck.

```
-- get JobName
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")

-- setup folder paths
set loc to path to desktop as text
set downloadsFolder to path to downloads folder as text
set newfo to loc & JobName & ":"
set newfoSeps to newfo & JobName & "_Seps" & ":"
set newfoDTG to newfo & JobName & "_DTG" & ":"

-- make sure all of the folders exist
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder newfo) then
        make new folder at loc with properties {name:JobName}
    end if

    if not (exists folder newfoSeps) then
        make new folder at folder newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_Seps"}
    end if

    if not (exists folder newfoDTG) then
        make new folder at folder newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_DTG"}
    end if
end tell

set the clipboard to JobName -- this is not a Finder command so we do not put it in the Finder block of code

-- move files to newfo and get a list of them
tell application "Finder"
    open folder newfo
    move (files of folder downloadsFolder) to folder newfo
    set newfoFiles to (files of folder newfo) as alias list
end tell

-- open each file in Illustrator and do your stuff
repeat with aFile in newfoFiles
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        open aFile
        tell document 1
            set docColorSpace to color space
            if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
                set SpotColor1 to {cyan:21.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
                set SpotColor2 to {cyan:11.0, magenta:100, yellow:30.0, black:0.0}
                set SpotColor3 to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0, yellow:0.0, black:100.0}
            else
                set SpotColor1 to {red:206.0, green:219.0, blue:41.0}
                set SpotColor2 to {red:215.0, green:23.0, blue:111.0}
                set SpotColor3 to {red:35.0, green:34.0, blue:33.0}
            end if

            make new spot with properties {name:"Highlight White", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor1}
            make new spot with properties {name:"Under Base", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor2}
            make new spot with properties {name:"Spot Black", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor3}
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Your script works great! The first section I had worked but when I added the part to command Illustrator is when it had problems so your explanation is very helpful. I really struggled with the downloads folder bit and I really like how your script eliminates the need for the (files of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Yourusernamehere:Downloads"). The Illustrator section came right from the Adobe manual so I didn't understand why it wasn't working every time.

Comment: At some point I may attempt to fully automate the entire process (between chrome, filemaker,finder and illustrator) but Im thinking it may be best to try this with javascript? I have a lot to learn but appreciate the help! i named the script after your username.

Comment: file something of folder something of folder something of disk something    i wish i had found this earlier - this should be somewhere more visible for noobs.

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful. If this answers your question please mark this (check it) as the answer so others know you found a solution.